# SQL Only return value if condition is met with duplicate info

Tags: sql, between, strict

I want to write a SQL query that only returns "Item" from the database only if a strict condition is met. Effectively I want to say "Get Item only if MyValue is never between 6 and 9.

```
 Item | MyValue
   1  |  3
   1  |  6
   1  |  9
   1  |  12
   2  |  1
   2  |  4
   3  |  3
   3  |  6
   3  |  9
```

I've come up with:

```
  SELECT * FROM data WHERE(MyValue NOT BETWEEN 6 and 9)
```

but that gets me this:

```
   1  |  3
   1  |  12
   2  |  1
   2  |  4
   3  |  3
```

Where as the goal is to simply obtain this:

```
 Item |
   2  |
```

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Item 
FROM data
WHERE item NOT IN(SELECT Item 
                  FROM data 
                  WHERE Myvalue BETWEEN 6 AND 9);
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acebd/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select item
from t
group by item
having sum(case when MyValue BETWEEN 6 and 9 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows that have values between 6 and 9.  It passes when no rows have this condition.